# How can we unwind a Index ( SPX ) Variance swap?

Tags: derivatives, finance-mathematics, variance

Client A comes to dealer to trade variance notional $1m at T=0. The trade is executed with dealer short volatility with strike of 20.

term Payoff of dealer = notional*( Stike^2 - realized vol^2 )

now at t=T1 the client , comes back with the order to reduce the notional of variance swap by half.

How can the dealer hedge the remaining portfolio ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since variance is additive, your var swap at $t=t_1$ is the same as the realized cash pnl plus a new var swap traded on $t=t_1$ with strike being $K_1$ rather than $K_0$, with a variance amount being $\frac{T - t_1}{T}$ times the original variance amount, where $K_1$ is the fair strike on $t=t_1$ and $K_0$ is your old strike traded on $t=0$.

If you would like to unwind (part of) the var swap, what you are doing is just trading a new var swap with the same maturity as the old var swap. Therefore the dealer just hedge as how they normally hedge when trading var swaps.

Comment: Yes, it is included in the cash pnl needed to be settled when unwinding.

Comment: Thanks for this. if  I try to solve this by equation I can cancel by exposure to realised volatility and I am left with .                                                                             Following term.  $Notional*( K_{t,T}^2 - K_{0,T}^2)$.                                                                  1) Will the dealer charge this cost to exit the swap ?                                                    
2) People often quote this as vega cost /charge. what exactly is that ? How exactly the dealer estimate this vega cost to be charged to the client   ?

Comment: 1. This is included in the cash to be settled when unwinding. Probably I should not use the term realized cash pnl, what I mean by this is actually the sum of the realized vol pnl + implied vol pnl. 2. I have not heard of this term. When unwinding, you usually quote different dealers rather than just the one with whom you trade the original swap to find the best $K_1$. The key point is that this so called "unwind" is essentially just short/long a new var swap to offset your original long/short var position. Therefore there is no "cost", you just trade as normal.